# curl tries to connect to 127.0.0.1:9050 by default

Tags: curl

whenever I use curl it tries to connect to tor service by default. my tor service is turned off and network proxy is disabled in network settings.

here is the output of the command `curl google.com`:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9050: Connection refused
```

I didn't change any configuration of curl to use Tor.

my OS is ubuntu 17.10

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try using "curl --noproxy * google.com" This will disable the use of a proxy server for all addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Check your environment variables with some command as `env` at the command interface line. Perhaps some variable as http_proxy or HTTPS_PROXY is set.

Another way to bypass the setting of these environment variables is to launch `curl --noproxy '*' google.com` to see if the unwanted behaviour still happens.

The `curl` command has also a configuration file where some options can be set (See `~/.curlrc` in the cse of default settings).

Comment: I don't have such environment variables. `--noproxy` flag also returns `curl: no URL specified!`. I don't have any `~/.curlrc` nor configuration under /etc

Comment: The `--noproxy` flag must be followed by a wildcard, v.gr. `*`, otherwise www.google.com will be considered as the argument of `--noproxy` and `curl` will return 'no URL specified!'. I eddited my answer above. See the correct way to launch `curl` and escape the `*`.

Comment: that solved my problem thanks! but is there any way to use curl without this flag? there are lots of scripts which use curl and its hard to change them to use this flag

Comment: You can define these settings in the `~/.curlrc` configuration file.